# Github development, deployment process for ios apps

Tags: ios, git, mobile, github

we have a team of 3 and have about 10 clients for our branded/customized apps

All of the customized apps have a central code base in git (master).

We would like to use git as the central repository for all of the apps.

What we would like to achieve is:
we will set up a code base as master, it has its dummy graphics and data.
Each time we have a new client, we will make a new branch (client1). Update graphics and customize the app, then we deploy to the production.

So developers will work on their local machines, make a sub branch (client1-1, client1-2) etc
then commit back to parent branch (client1).

Later, if we want to commit a change from client 1-1 all the way back to master, is that possible?

Also, is that the standard development process for iOS app ?

Comment: Yes it is. A great resource I found for setting up a good branching model with Git was [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: this is pretty cool model, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I feel that is not a good idea because, when you deploy to production or merge with the master, you will be practically be spending a lot of time on merge conflicts, then getting the code to the production. If i were you, I will have 10 different git repositories and if a new customer comes, then i will create a new one. Since, git is free, creating a repository will not be difficult. Saves you a lot of time and tension as well. Once the repository is ready, then clear all your production to make it as if new. Then push the ready repository. Hope this helps...

Comment: but we also want to make some changes to the code base (master) and push to all of the branches like major updates